# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.creat - Jersey

Tags: java, maven, jersey, http-status-code-500

I am making first simple RESTFul API to my project and I am using Maven. Frist, I created the maven archetype jersey-quickstart-webapp with default API. I've added my files, added dependencies. However when I use API URL: localhost:8080/webapi/myresource -> I've got 500 error here it is:

**HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error**

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Exception**

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**Root Cause**

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createLocator(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:114)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:86)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:62)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:79)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:97)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:93)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.33

And this is how my pom.xml file looks like:
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes</groupId>
<artifactId>ParkingSystem</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ParkingSystem</name>

<build>
    <finalName>ParkingSystem</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
     <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-b42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
</project>
```

I am using Netbeans and Tomcat. I thought the error is caused because of lack hk2-api dependency, but nothing changed when I've added it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've found the solution. My bad! I copied by mistake libraries that I download manually before I started to use Maven. After I delete all those .jar files everything starts to work. Sorry, that's my bad, the question can be closed.